# Saving string column into NetCdf file

Tags: string, matlab, char, netcdf

I want to save string data into a single column in the NetCDF file using MATLAB, there are no options given for string. Can someone tell me how to save string data into the NetCDF file?

```
S_rebuilt=["101670";"101670";"101670";"101670"]

nccreate('file_name.nc','S_rebuilt',...
     'Dimensions', {'x',size(S_rebuilt,1),'y',size(S_rebuilt,2)},...
     'FillValue','disable');

ncwrite('file_name.nc','S_rebuilt',S_rebuilt);
```

Comment: You have numeric data. Why do you want to save it as string?

Comment: No, I have string data too. These are merely a few lines that include numbers. But I have other string (characters) data of equal rows and column which I want to save in NetCDF files.

Comment: As this question had no help within so many days, I suggest switching to Python or some other popular programming language :)

Answer (score 0):

With using format `netcdf4`, one can use datatype `string` in the MatLab. So, to save the variable S_rebuilt as string, I suggest code:

```
filename = 'file_name.nc'
S_rebuilt = ["101670";"101670";"101670";"101670"]

nccreate(filename,'S_rebuilt',...
     'Dimensions', {'nvars',length(S_rebuilt)},...
     'Datatype','string','format','netcdf4');
% ----------------------------------------------
ncwrite(filename,'S_rebuilt',S_rebuilt);
```